# не работает код из документации. почему?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Код, приведенный ниже, взят из [доков](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#extension-origin), но в ответе приходит пустая строка:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), true);
xhr.send();

function handleStateChange() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(xhr.status) // 0
    console.log(xhr.responseText) // ""
  }
}

chrome.runtime.getURL(...) // -- то же самое

console.log(chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json')) // возвращает правильный путь, по которому можно перейти из консоли "chrome.runtime.getURL('/config_resources/config.json')"
```

Ну, почему так? Может у меня камплюктор не для айтишников?
Только не говорите, что дело во мне.

Comment: У Вас Синтакс Егор =) знаете такого?

Comment: я сам здесь Синтакс Егор, как я уже понял. объясните, что неправильно я написал. пажалста!

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange(); Скобки при вызове функции. console.log(xhr.status); точка с запятой в конце команды, следующая строчка тоже самое.

Comment: после каждой команды идёт точка с запятой, у Вас дальше еще пропущено в chrome.runtime.getURL

Comment: вряд ли проблема в этом. в javascript можно не ставить ;

Comment: функция отрабатывает, значит и не в скобках тоже) более того, со скобками она не срабатывает) это же присвоение обработчика, так-то

Comment: В ошибке написана строка

Comment: Если вместо `chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json')` подставить реальный URL, будет то же самое? И вообще, у Вас в этом файле что-нибудь есть?

Comment: а? такое чувство, что для XHR это не тот путь, он говорит: _chrome-extension://invalid/ 0 ()_
хотя из _consol.log()_ в браузере по ссылке перейти можно

Comment: если добавить в **"permissions"** в _"manifest.json"_, то работает сторонний урл. да, файл не пустой, и линтер не ругается

Comment: наверно дело в моем недолинуксе.. или именно во мне. да, я понял, дело во мне. простите, что отвлек.